# build and install word officejs add ins

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

i have developed a task pane word addin with yo and js

the thing  is when i built it i have html files and manifest.xml file but i don't know how to install these files inside word (windows)

i used this command from package.json:

```
npm run build
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "office-addin-taskpane-js",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-TaskPane-JS.git"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "app_to_debug": "word",
    "app_type_to_debug": "desktop",
    "dev_server_port": 3000
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "dev-server": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "lint": "office-addin-lint check",
    "lint:fix": "office-addin-lint fix",
    "prettier": "office-addin-lint prettier",
    "start": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml",
    "start:desktop": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml desktop",
    "start:web": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml web",
    "stop": "office-addin-debugging stop manifest.xml",
    "validate": "office-addin-manifest validate manifest.xml",
    "watch": "webpack --mode development --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.13.0",
    "@types/office-js": "^1.0.180",
    "@types/office-runtime": "^1.0.17",
    "acorn": "^8.5.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-office-addins": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "office-addin-cli": "^1.3.5",
    "office-addin-debugging": "^4.3.8",
    "office-addin-dev-certs": "^1.7.7",
    "office-addin-lint": "^2.0.0",
    "office-addin-manifest": "^1.7.7",
    "office-addin-prettier-config": "^1.1.4",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "source-map-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.5",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "webpack": "^5.50.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "4.7.3"
  },
  "prettier": "office-addin-prettier-config",
  "browserslist": [
    "ie 11"
  ]
}
```

can anyone help me build it the right way then install it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to run the dev server. The `scripts` section lists available commands you could use for that:

```
"dev-server": "webpack serve --mode development",
```

So, you could use the following command line:

```
npm run dev-server
```

Then you can launch the host application, the `scripts` section defines the following entries for that:

```
"start": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml",
"start:desktop": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml desktop",
"start:web": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml web",
```

Depending on your choice (whether it is a desktop application or browser) you could choose one to run. For example:

```
npm run start:desktop
```

In that case the desktop edition of Excel will be run and the add-in sideloaded.

You can read more about that in the [Overview of debugging Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-overview) article.